# Exceeding update depth with userReducer but not with useState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state

I have an useEffect that triggers every time an user types something in the input.
At first I had it running with an useState and it was working smooth as butter, but I was required to change it to useReducer.
The useEffect with useReducer:

```
useEffect(() => {
dispatch({type : 'username', payload : watch().username});
dispatch({type : 'password', payload : watch().password});
console.log(state.username, state.password);
}, [watch()]);
```

The useEffect with useState :

```
useEffect(() => {
setPassword(watch().password);
setUsername(watch().username);
console.log(username, password);
}, [watch()]);
```

And the useEffect constantly is being triggered even when the users is not typing anything, as when used with useState it does not do that.

The reducer :

```
 const reducer = (state, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
  case "username":
    return {...state, username: action.payload };
  case "password":
    return {...state, password : action.payload};
}
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few red flags here, but the main one that stands out is how you're using `watch()`. `useEffect` and `useState` will (likely) be re-running on every render because `watch()` is *probably* returning a non-memoized object. The reason your code "works" using `useState` is because [setting a state object to the same thing does nothing](https://blog.thoughtspile.tech/2021/09/27/usestate-tricks/) - if the username or password isn't changing, the state doesn't get updated, so your component doesn't re-render.

This isn't true with `useReducer` though, unless you explicitly cater for it in your reducer function - something like this will probably fix the bug:

```js
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "username":
      return state.username !== action.payload
        ? {...state, username: action.payload }
        : state;

    case "password":
      return state.password !== action.payload
        ? {...state, password: action.payload }
        : state;

    default: 
      return state;
  }
};
```

However, you should also try and make the dependencies for hooks as simple as possible. Is there any reason you couldn't call `watch()` first, and then pass the values to your effect?

```js
const { username, password } = watch();

useEffect(() => {
  dispatch({type : 'username', payload : username});
  dispatch({type : 'password', payload : password});
}, [username, password]);
```

Or, you could go one better and separate the two into two different effects - there's no need to dispatch a `username` update if the `password` has changed:

```js
const { username, password } = watch();

useEffect(() => {
  dispatch({type : 'username', payload : username});
}, [username]);

useEffect(() => {
  dispatch({type : 'password', payload : password});
}, [password]);
```

And, while we're in refactoring mode, why not create a custom hook to handle the logic for you? Something like:

```js
const useLoginFormState = (formValues) => {
  const { username, password } = formValues;

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({type : 'username', payload : username});
  }, [username]);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({type : 'password', payload : password});
  }, [password]);

  return formValues;
}

// Now in your component -
const MyComponent = () => {
  const formValues = useLoginFormState(watch());
};
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for giving me your time and writing this long and informational answer. This does fix my issue and I understood what mistake I made, which in essence was quite easy to overcome. Thanks a lot!